# Copying files while maintaining file attributes

Tags: shell-script, tar, cp

Say, if I want to copy /etc/bin to a folder while maintaining the file attributes as well as parent directories. [The target folder should not just contain bin folder but /etc/bin.]

Is the possible to do this? Do zipping and unzipping using tar works?

Comment: tar always work.

Comment: What about ownership?

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir target/etc
cp -Rp /etc/bin target/etc/
```

or (GNU only)

```
mkdir target/etc
cp -a /etc/bin target/etc/
```

or

```
mkdir target/etc
rsync -aAX /etc/bin target/etc/
```

or (classic unix)

```
find /etc/bin | cpio -pm target
```

or (classic unix, the other )

```
( cd / && tar -tf - etc/bin ) | (cd target && tar -xf - )
```

or (the POSIX replacement that few people seem to have heard of)

```
mkdir target/etc
pax -rw -pe etc/bin target/etc/
```

All of these preserve traditional Unix metadata (permissions, timestamps¹, ownership if run as root². Depending on your system, they may or may not preserve additional metadata such as ACL and extended attributes (some of them may require additional options, e.g. `--acls --xattrs` with GNU tar).

¹  <sub>Except for the ctime which can't be copied, and for directory atimes for some methods.</sub> 
²  <sub>Only root can preserve ownership.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

man tar:

> ```
>    -P, --absolute-names
>           Don't strip leading slashes from file names  when  creating  ar‐
>           chives.
>
>    -p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
>           extract information about file permissions  (default  for  supe‐
>           ruser)
>
>    --xattrs
>           Enable extended attributes support.
> ```

Comment: What about ownership?

Comment: ask the manual.

Comment: Very kind of you.